# Laravel's Queue withChain, can't make them run sequentially

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to make a chain of jobs, let's say i have 100 videos to process, with this code i would expect that `DownloadThumbnail` executes once, then it passes the ball to `DownloadSource`, then to `UploadToS3` and `ConvertVideoToH264`.

What I'm seeing when consuming the queue is that it does all `DownloadThumbnail` first, then all `DownloadSource` etc etc. Which is not what I wanted it to do. What is the best approach to have jobs run sequentially? thanks!

```
foreach($hundreds as $video){

    $Tasks = [];

    //takes few seconds
    if(!$video->thm){
        $Tasks[] = new DownloadThumbnail($video);
    }

    //takes 10 minutes
    if(!$video->dl){
        $Tasks[] = new DownloadSource($video);
    }

    //takes 10 minutes
    if(!$video->s3){
        $Tasks[] = new UploadToS3($video);
    }

    //takes 5 minutes
    if($video->transcoded < 3){
        $Tasks[] = new ConvertVideoToH264($video);
    }


    if(!empty($Tasks)){
        $first_job = array_shift($Tasks);
        $first_job::withChain($Tasks)->dispatch($video)->allOnQueue('processvideos');
    }

}
```